# getStaticProps generates static JSON data on page, how is that SEO friendly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Next.js `getStaticProps` passes your data to the page at build time, generates static JSON data on page.

It is up to the page React to compose the data into components. So SEO would not see the actual list of HTML Data directly, right? how is that SEO-friendly?

I mean, for example, your page has:

```
/* static data list given by static page */
const data = [{..},{..}...];
...
<ul>
  {data.map(item => 
    <li>{item.text}</li>)}
</ul>
```

This component is post-rendering on the client side, SEO won't see the list of `ul-li`s. So, how is this getStaticProps() making SEO happier? Or am I misunderstanding it? It doesn't make SEO happier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we have the below code in a `pages/index.js`. It's a simple Next.js page. If you run `yarn build` and open `.next/server/pages/index.html`, you would see the flowing output.

Code:

```js
// pages/index.js

export default function Home({ posts }) {
  return (
    <>
      {posts.map((p) => (
        <div key={p.id}>
          <h1>{p.title}</h1>
          <p>{p.body}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  const data = await res.json();
  return {
    props: {
      posts: data.slice(0, 2),
    },
  };
}
```

Output:

```html
<body>
  <div id="__next">
    <div>
      <h1>sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit</h1>
      <p>
        quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae
        ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>qui est esse</h1>
      <p>
        est rerum tempore vitae sequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque
        fugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis qui aperiam non
        debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">
    {
      "props": {
        "pageProps": {
          "posts": [
            {
              "userId": 1,
              "id": 1,
              "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
              "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
            },
            {
              "userId": 1,
              "id": 2,
              "title": "qui est esse",
              "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

As you can see, the output contains your React components as plain HTML tags, instead of an empty body as for a normal React application. This is why we say Next.js is good for SEO.

Now, Next.js uses the data inside the script, to transform those plain HTML tags to React components on the browser, for client interactivities. This process is called [hydration](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/hydrateRoot).

Comment: Thank you for the actual example to explain the myth :)